# Could not load file or assembly sapnco_utils.DLL or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, sap-dotnet-connector

I am using VS 2022 64 bit.. When I am trying to run my API project based on SAP .NET Connector locally.. then coming this error..

I have tried almost all solutions from Stack Overflow.. but still it is not working.

Like clean Nuget packages and reinstall them.
Delete Bin and Obj folder and rebuild solution multiple times.

**Even I have set to 64 but still not working..**

Any help or advice..

Thanks

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if in your system is it installed Visual C++ 2010 SP1

If not just install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package from here and you shall be fine